# How to set the output of a command to an exported variable in AWS Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm creating a service/frontend.  The service is being created using CloudFormation.  An ApiKey is being used for authentication.  The value of the ApiKey isn't available to CloudFormation, so I can't set the environment variable when I create the CodeBuild enviornment.  I have exported the ApiKey Id, in the hopes of getting the ApiKey value during CodeBuild via the aws cli.

I'm calling the `get-api-key`, which returns my key value as expected.  I just can't seem to figure out how to set this to an environment variable.  What am I missing?

I've tried a few things, thus far.  Always the same result, where the key isn't found.  My CloudFormation template creates an env variable of name 'REACT_APP_API_KEY' and sets it to an empty string (I did this because it complains if I try to export a new variable).  I've confirmed that 'REACT_APP_API_KEY' exists via the `printenv` command.

My buildspec.yaml is as follows

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    S3_BUCKET: "nacho-bucket"
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
      - echo Installing npm dependencies
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Retrieving API key value
      - aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key $API_KEY_ID --include-value | jq '.value'
      - REACT_APP_API_KEY = $(aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key $API_KEY_ID --include-value | jq '.value')
      - echo $REACT_APP_API_KEY
      - printenv
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Deploying UI to environment $S3_BUCKET
      - cd build
      - 'aws s3 sync . s3://$S3_BUCKET --delete'
```

Console output:

```
[Container] 2020/10/19 19:19:36 Running command echo Retrieving API key value
Retrieving API key value

[Container] 2020/10/19 19:19:36 Running command aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key $API_KEY_ID --include-value | jq '.value'
"correctapikey"

[Container] 2020/10/19 19:19:42 Running command REACT_APP_API_KEY = $(aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key $API_KEY_ID --include-value | jq '.value')
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: REACT_APP_API_KEY: not found

[Container] 2020/10/19 19:19:42 Command did not exit successfully REACT_APP_API_KEY = $(aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key $API_KEY_ID --include-value | jq '.value') exit status 127
```

Answer (score 3):

Arg.  I've spent most of a day trying to figure this out.  The fix is below (can't have spaces around the equals operator).

```
- REACT_APP_API_KEY=$(aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key $API_KEY_ID --include-value | jq -r '.value')
```

Comment: I'm curious if you tried it with the export keyword before REACT_APP_API_KEY. Isn't that the normal way to set an environment variable? I'm having a similar issue but thought it was because CodeBuild doesn't support command substitution ( $(command...) )

Comment: Upvote. Seems so obvious now. One issue: if this fails, I don't think the error will propagate, potentially resulting in false positives. Maybe add some error checks around the `REACT_APP_API_KEY` output